# EmberJS - How to Globally set an property of all component?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a piece of data (object) that is printed as a global variable from server side script.

```
user = { id : 1, name: 'foo', avatar : 'http://foo.com/avatar.jpg'}
```

This piece of information is requires in various part of the whole application including some components.

I know I can go through each component controller and set a property to save the user object.

```
App.FooBarComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    user: user
});


App.AnotherFooComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    user: user
});
```

**How do I reduce this repetition?** Is there a way I can set the property for all the components so the variable is available to **handlebars expression**?

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="components/foo-bar">
    <h1>{{user.name}}</h1>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="components/another-foo">
    <h1>{{user.name}}</h1>
</script>
```

I was under the impression that I should be able to access any global js variables from handlebar expression. But I seems isn't the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your application controller for this purpose :)

```
 <h1>{{controllers.application.user.name}}</h>
```

However you will `need` your `ApplicationController` in the controllers :)

Another way is to make a custom Component qand then extend it like

```
 App.MyComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
      user : user
 });
 AppFooComponent = App.MyComponent.extend({
     //user is gotten from MyComponent
 });
```

Comment: Example for how to use `needs` can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/a/18386236/550907

Answer (score 1):

Use Ember.Application.inject (http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Application.html#method_inject)

```
var user = Ember.Object.create({
    id : 1,
    name: 'foo', avatar : 'http://foo.com/avatar.jpg'
});
App.register('user:main', user);
App.inject('component', 'user', 'user:main');
```

Then in your component templates just do

```
{{user.name}}
```